# How to add a shortcut key (solved)

Tags: shortcut

I want to add a short key to mark seam.

So I selected the edge and press ctrl+E and with the mark seam I right click on it and selected Add shortcut and press the key that is dot beside shift in the pc keyboard.

When I start to press it works awesome. But the problem is when I open a new file there is no shortcut key to mark seam.

Then I tried again same way and save with the save startup file. But same after open a new file the shortcut key disappear.

How can I fix or keep permanently my shortcut key? And how to know which key is available in blender that can I put on that shortcut? Any suggestion or help?

[image]

**Answer : After adding the shortcut i have to save user settings in user preferences.**

Comment: You need to save preferences, not startup file. Use the bottom left button in user preferences window...

Comment: @m.ardito That i miss i think so. Thanks for reminder it work

Comment: @atek you've  been around this site long enough to know not to edit the question as "solved", and also not to write the answer as part of the question. Please write an answer to your own question and mark  that as "accepted".